# Crawl Twitter Users and Followers Data

Tags: twitter, web-crawler, social-networking, twitter4j

I have a large database of twitter users (about 6 million). I have the user ids, login handle, their recent tweets, contact details, location etc.

I want to build a user-follower list out of these. Basically I want to create another table which will have two-columns -
1) User-ID (the id of the user which I have)
2) Follower-ID (the ids, separated by a semicolon - of all the followers of this user)

For example: if an user with id 001 is is being followed users with ids 002,003 the record would look like this -

User-ID - 001
Follower-ID - 002;003

I want to achieve this using Java preferably, but I am open to other languages as well.

I tried using twitter4j - a Java library to get tweets, users etc - but it has a limitation on number of API calls a day.
Using the twitter SEARCH OR REST API is not possible since it does not give me the ids of the followers of a particular user.

Another way my professor suggested me - to crawl the webpages of Twitter. 
For example - if a user handle is xxx then I need to crawl following link -

https://twitter.com/xxx/followers

Get this webpage and parse HTML to get follower IDs. I checked the webpage using Firebug and I could see the IDs of all followers !!

The problem here is - How do I do it for 6 million users that I have? (I have the handles, so I just need to crawl the link mentioned above, replacing xxx with next handle)

I was trying to use Crawleer4j - a web crawler to crawl twitter pages, but since Twitter has increased their security - this is also not possible.

How can I do this? Please help - I am doing this as a part of my research project and I am really stuck here.

I want to find out a way by which I can crawl Twitter web pages to get this required information.

Please help !

Comment: "Twitter has increased their security" specifically because they don't want you doing this... If you have a valid use for this data for a research project, why don't you try contacting them and asking for it directly? (If nothing else, you risk getting stung by rate limits - at 1 user per second, it would take two and a half months to get 6 million users' data...)

Answer (score 3):

I would start with the links below. It can be done but it is going to take a a considerable amount of time.

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/followers/ids

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/friends/ids

Consider that Justin Beiber has 40,000,000 followers so pulling with one token would take 5 1/2 days.

40,000,000 (followers) / 5,000 (records returned in a call) / 15 (max rest calls in a 15 min period)/ 4 (15 mins intervals in 1 hr) = 133 hours

Comment: I am working on something similar. Have you figured this out or found a solution, would love to work together. I am using it for a different reason for sure, and nothing illegal or bad. I am wanting to find legitimate accounts suspended as well as youtube and FB.